# What is the maximum value at unsigned 7downto0 in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I have some question about verilog.

If I have unsigned value to  reg A[7:0], then how do I make maximum, or minimum value?
Also, If I have signed value to reg A[7:0], then how do I make maximum, or minimum value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you interpret an 8-bit number as unsigned, the range of the number is between `00000000` and `11111111` which are `0` to `(2^8 - 1)=255`. 
For signed, one bit is used for sign. So the positive range will be from `00000000` to `01111111`, which are `0` to `2^7-1=127`, and the negative range is represented in 2's complement form `11111111` to `10000000` which are `-1` to `-2^7=-128`. 
 In general, given `N` bits, the unsigned range would be `[0, 2^N-1]`. Signed range would be `[-2^(N-1), 2^(N-1)-1]`

Comment: Thanks then What about at signed?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like like you are coming from a language like VHDL which has subtypes that allow you to define a minimum and maximum value range for a variable. Verilog has no such concept. The closest thing would be a pattern matched tagged union in SystemVerilog.